# Failed to find target with hash string 'android-24' in macOS

Tags: android, macos, android-ndk

macOS Sierra

Android Studio Version 2.2.3

android-ndk-r13b

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbQFb.jpg)

I have click "install missing platforms and sync project",now,in my directory android-ndk-r13b/platforms/,i did have android-24.

But the error still happens! Somebody else say that should edit file build.gradle,now my build.gradle contents is follow:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mimo520.arderbud.myfirstandroidapplication"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 'N'
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner  "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        } 
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

so how to fix this file? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please, post your app's build.gradle (you've posted your project's build.gradle).

Often this problem is that you haven't current buildtools version, or your compile version doesn't match with the version of your buildtools and so on.

Comment: i have change to the app's build.gradle.how to fix it?